# Display link, not tag

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, html

I have a list of html tags, called papersFound, e.g.

```
papersFound = ['<a href="http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9801077v2" target = "_blank">Symmetric spectra</a>', '<a href="http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9706228v1" target = "_blank">Topological transformation groups</a>']
```

I want to loop through this list, and display hyperlinks to the papers, not the tags themselves (obviously).  What I have now is displaying the tags:

```
{% for paper in papersFound %}
            <li class="list-group-item" style="color:black">{{ paper }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

EDIT: At http://jinja.pocoo.org, I see the example

```
<ul>
{% for user in users %}
<li><a href="{{ user.url }}">{{ user.username }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I want to implement this.  But what kind of object is users (which has properties url and username)?

EDIT 2: Currently, my page is displaying the html tags, as you can see
[image]

Comment: What seems to be the problem?

Comment: can you add the current output and expected output ? also, is it flask ?

Comment: It is a python/django app.

Comment: I believe currently the engine is escaping the tag, resulting in outputting the string as string, not as html tag. Have a look through the documentation, check whether they have something to stop the escape.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Which documentation should I be looking through?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need the **[safe](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#safe)** keyword. `{{ paper| safe  }}`

EX:

```
papersFound  = ['<a href="http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9801077v2" target = "_blank">Symmetric spectra</a>', '<a href="http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9706228v1" target = "_blank">Topological transformation groups</a>']

s = """{% for paper in papersFound %}
            <li class="list-group-item" style="color:black">{{ paper| safe  }}</li>
{% endfor %}"""
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get your `href` value to hold your data on empty div.Loop and get `herf` value and again empty your div.

```js
var papersFound = ['<a href="http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9801077v2" target = "_blank">Symmetric spectra</a>', '<a href="http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9706228v1" target = "_blank">Topological transformation groups</a>']
var arrayLength = papersFound.length;
var html = '';
for (i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
  html += papersFound[i];
}
$('.results').html(html);
$('.results').find('a').each(function(index, element) {
  console.log($(this).attr('href'));
});
$('.results').html('');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='results'>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  When I run your code, I get a list of urls.  What I want is a list of paper titles, where each title is a link to the arxiv page for the paper.

Comment: What is list of paper titles? You want to bind this url in new tittles then loop and rebind.